# style in wpf when targeted only on textblock, also applies same style to button contents automatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

[image]I am really wondering why the below code makes the color or button content also orange in WPF when it is clearly targeted only for Textblock. When I change the target to button, it works fine and gets applied only for button content and not to textblock. Why is this strange behavior ?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="orange" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the code :)

Comment: @nakiya: No :( Sorry, I dont know whats the technical isue with Stackoverflow. I did add the code, its not displaying. Even I edited now, it displays in edit place but now once I submit. Well for you the code is : <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="orange" />
</Style>

Comment: Because a `Button` contains a `TextBlock`. You likely want to be targetting your styles (or at least most aspects of your styles) at something higher level than a `TextBlock`, like a `Label`.

Comment: @Divine: it is not a stackoverflow problem. Indent 4 spaces for code.

Comment: @KentBoogaart: I wouldn't appreciate that from Microsoft. It doesn't make sense. If I say TextBlock, it should apply to TextBlock only. What is that then the MS claiming, reducing developer efforts and fostering RAD. I would rather say, it worsen's developer efforts

Comment: @KentBoogaart: Thanks Kent, I will again follow it. However, I did that, sometime it works good and sometime it is not :(

Comment: @KentBoogaart: If you say so, then I would argue that, when I target Button, it should even be applicable for textblock texts. It certainly will not make any sense at all. Why is that so many complexities in WPF/SL. It certainly doesn't interest!

Comment: I don't see the behavior you describe: When I create a new window, and add that style to `Window.Resources`, the `TextBlock` control get the orange text, but my `Button` does not. Are you sure there's nothing else going on?

Comment: @dlev: Indeed I am very sure, even Kent is supporting that behavior above. Dlev, but I add this into App.Resources while I see you do it in Window.Resources. Now I don't know whats the difference between these two :D Do you see it is because of that ?

Comment: @Divine Nope, App.Resources doesn't change anything. Which version of WPF are you using?

Comment: @dlev: I dont know. Its been a while since I worked on VS, I have VS2010 and just started on WPF. I dont know how to find the WPF version. How to find it ? I think it should be the version associated with .NET 4 ? I guess ?!! Because I do have VS 2010 which works on .NET 4 right right ?

Comment: Yes, it would likely be WPF 4.0. I actually do see the behavior you're see. As Kent says, the default data template for button text is a `TextBlock`, so your style is going to affect that.

Comment: @dlev: Ok, but why it is not the same case at your end. I am sure as you did just a test now in your VS, you must be using the default template of button as well. Why you are not getting same behavior ? :(

Comment: Sorry, I *can* see the behavior now.

Comment: @dlev: Intriguing. It is something similar to Microsoft OS problems, where it boots suddenly when I shutdown (Many times I encountered) lol. Well mysterious. I wish, these kind of silly issues should be addressed by MS. I am sure experienced geeks can solve this problem by themselves, but newbies like me, and at the pressure of delivering output, will struggle most of the times... Anyway...Thanks dlev for the critique. If you come across any tidings on this, please share, I would appreciate that. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically most of the text you see in WPF `Window` is eventually converted into `TextBlock`. If you specify `<Button Content="ABC"/>` what WPF will actually do is put `<TextBlock Text="ABC"/>` into `Button.Content` when its `ContentPresenter` creates visual tree. So your implicit style does not apply to `Button` but to `TextBlock` which is part of its content.
In WPF control has its default template which is build from other controls that can be build from other controls until eventually every text ends up as `TextBlock` that's why Microsoft put protection in place and normally implicit `Style` is applied in templates only to elements inherited from [`System.Windows.Controls.Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx) to protect most basic elements like [`TextBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx), which is inherited straight from [`System.Windows.FrameworkElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx), from unknowingly applying complicated styles that could cause unwanted behaviour, performance issues or errors. Therefore is you specify your implicit `TextBlock` style in `Window.Resources`, or in one of its child items, it won't be applied automatically in templates and your `Button` will keep default color, unless you move it into `Application.Resources` then it will apply also in templates and your `Button` text will become orange.

Comment: Hi DK, It was very convincing answer for me to understand. Thank you so much for explaining me in simple English that I can chew. Now, I can explain the same if someone asks me of this behavior or problem. As you mentioned, I will try to keep it in Windows.Resources and see if I get default thing. But as a starter, I don't know how to do that, I will read few blogs. Thanks again, I appreciate your very humble reply. Cheers

Comment: DK, is there a way for me to see the visual tree for every control or class ? I am new, I don't know how to see visual tree in VS especially for these WPF controls. Please guide me at your convenience. Thank you

Comment: @Divine, for example put a breakpoint on Click event, in debugger hover `sender` variable and click magnifying glass icon and it should show you current visual tree. You can also do it from immediate window

Comment: Hi Dkozl, Thank you for helping me, I have pasted the picture above, could you please tell me if I located the right textblock under the Button in Visual tree (Encircled) ? Is that what you were talking about ?

Comment: Dkozl, I am also happy to learn more, I could control the color of button by just putting a Null style in the TextBlock under Button, simple. But, it could be tedious if I have to do it for all buttons, so as you mentioned putting it in Window.Resources would be a nice solution, what I understand is.

Comment: Yes, that is the `TextBlock` created by `ContentPresenter`, that is part of default template, to accommodate your text

Comment: Thank you DK, I learned a lot. I will experiment on it more :) Its quite interesting....Thank you for your time in helping me... Cheers :) :)